# undefinded method instantiate while using the embed property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, polymorphic-associations

I am getting an error `undefined method "instantiate" for Address:Class`

while loading any of the pages which is using the `Address` model, like **new/edit** of **customer/site** page. All of the things were running fine but suddenly like a change, I felt some of the times when the address class is being used, the site is throwing an error irrespective of the scenario.

ADDRESS MODEL -

`embedded_in :addressable, polymorphic: true`

SITE MODEL -

`embeds_one :address, autobuild: true, as: :addressable`

CUSTOMER MODEL -

`embeds_one :address, autobuild: true, as: :addressable`

The error is random. Sometimes its smooth, but otherwise after refreshing 3-4 times on a page is automatically resolved.

Thank in advance.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here.

Comment: @JoshBrody Thanks for the look. I have added some more info regarding the issue. Please let me know if you need something else.

Comment: That still isn't enough information. We don't know how you're trying to use that code or what your workflow is.